# deploying servlet in oracle r12.2.6

Tags: oracle, jsp, servlets

We are into upgrade project from 11i to R12.2.6. We currently have an JSP that calls an servlet to fetch the data.

In 11i, this jsp called the servlet as
 `<a href="/oa_servlets/webportal.servlet.Test?deliveryId=<%=strDeliveryID%>&path=<%=strPath%>" target=_blank>`

This Test servlet picks up the blob data from the database table and writes it to a Servlet Output Stream. Thus clicking on the link will display a PDF.

Now in R12 , I am not able to call the servlet since I don't know where this oa_servlets is defined . I am getting 404 error .How should I call this servlet from my JSP?

Also I have placed this Test.java under $JAVA_TOP/webportal/servlet/.

Comment: can someone please provide an update on this?

Comment: can someone provide an update on the same?